# "fall to doing something"

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning

How grammatical is this passage from Of Mice And Men and what does it mean? Is "fall to do something" some phrase I don't know about? We see an ing-verb here, not a full infinitive as the case would be had Crooks just laid on his cot to rub his back with liniment

> He pulled out his shirt in back, poured a little liniment in his pink palm and, reaching around, he **fell slowly to rubbing his back**.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fall%20to found using Google search "fall to definition"

Comment: Absolutely normal. What research have you done?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey an insufficient one, apparently. I skimmed through Longman but didn't notice it ‍♂️

Comment: Very out of date, FYI. I’ve never heard someone say this in real life.

Comment: @cruthers - My father used to say things like 'What does she expect us to do? Fall to weeping and wailing?" when there was yet another sob story from a certain relative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated  by definitions from [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fall--to), [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fall+to), and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fall%20to), "*fall to*" is a phrasal verb that means " to begin some activity, ", "to start something", "to begin doing something". It is particularly used with eating, to the point that just "Fall to!" often means "[You may] start eating".

The example:

> ...  he fell slowly to rubbing his back.

means that he started the process of rubbing his back, and started it slowly. This is grammatically valid and natural, but now perhaps slightly old-fashioned.  (That would not have been true when *Of Mice and Men* was written.)

There is also another sense, meaning that responsibility for some task is assumed by or assigned to some person or entity. For example:

> - It fell to me to distribute the inheritances properly.
> - It falls to the government to ensure equal protection of the law.

This sense is somewhat formal or literary, and not often used in casual conversation.

Answer (score 0):

"Fall" or "Falling" into something is correct and was mostly said long ago.

- "Fall to Grace"
- "Fell into some money"
- "He fell into some bad luck"
- "She fell ill last night"